# Globally installed composer packages don't run

Tags: windows, path, composer-php

When I read instructions for global composer packages (ie. [PsySH](http://psysh.org/)), they makes it sound like you can just do

```
composer g require psy/psysh:@stable
```

and then

```
psysh
```

and so on for other such packages. Laravel is another one I have tried. ANyway, all I get when I try to run the tool is

> 'psysh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I didn't see the composer bin path in the PATH variable, so I added `%APPDATA%/Composer/vendor/bin`, where all the .bat files are for the globally installed packages, and I verified that the path works. Yet these tools won't run unless I am in the same bin directory as them. Anywhere else I get the error above...

Comment: Did you restart your command prompt after altering the path? Does the composer folder show up when you run `echo %PATH%` from the command prompt?

Comment: Yes I did, yes it does.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, had checked that composer had changed %path%... followed your answer and the issue was resolved. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Well that was silly. It didn't like the %APPDATA% part of the path, even though other paths use environment variables just fine. I replaced it with `C:\Users\MND\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`and then it works.